# How i can make a discord bot in specific channel delete and resends msg

Tags: discord, bots

How i can make a discord bot in specific channel and who ever write delete that message and resend it ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the bot to resend any message as the bot in a specific channel here's an example using [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/)

If I misunderstood and you want the bot to send a message as a specific user, that's not possible.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel.name === 'channel name') {
    msg.delete();
    msg.channel.send(msg.content);
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: that makes a infinity loop but if the loop stops its perfect

Comment: huh? Messages sent by the bot do not get processed by the bot

Comment: well its perfect but one problem yes the bot delete and send the message but it keep doing it again and again i try to fix it with break but im still getting error at break

Comment: sry for your eyes :P 

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel.id === 'channel id') 
    msg.delete();
  
  break;
  }

 msg.channel.send(msg.content);
})

client.login('token');

Comment: A break is only used in loops and switch statements, where as this has none. You are also sending the message in an unallowed location, as a client.on() parameter. Here's an example https://gist.github.com/DiamondMiner88/1f173ec68f5c639134382347a6df8740

Comment: yeah but it keeps deleting the message :v thats what im trying to fix m8

Comment: @Diamond Whether or not the message was sent by a bot application, the Client's "message" event will be fired regardless.

Comment: @Jakye The bot's own messages that it sent do not get processed by the message event. Other bot application's messages do however

Comment: @Diamond The bot's own messages do get processed. Here's an [example](https://imgur.com/a/4sfmxcx).

Comment: @Jakye Oh sorry didn't realize because I returned if the user that sent it is a bot.